# Wordpress widget don't show

Tags: php, wordpress

Got a weird issue here, so.. i've registerd my widget, and i can type/save it. But, when i visit the page, the text (or whatever is saved inside the widget) don't show?

Here is my simple code,

```
<?php the_widget('facebook-sidebar'); ?>
```

and

```
register_sidebar(array(

    'name'                  => 'Facebook',

    'id'                        => 'facebook-sidebar',

    'description'   => __( 'Located at the bottom of pages.'),

    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s">',

    'after_widget' => '</div>',

    'before_title' => '<h4>',

    'after_title' => '</h4>',

));
```

any suggestions on what i can do?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `the_widget()`, use `dynamic_sidebar('facebook-sidebar')`

Answer (score 0):

Do it like:

```
<?php 
 // Custom widget Area Start
 if ( !function_exists('facebook-sidebar') || !facebook-sidebar('Facebook') ) : ?>
<?php endif;
// Custom widget Area End
?>
```